# youtrack sharp DeserializationException

Tags: c#, youtrack

I am trying to write a cutomer portal that uses the YourackSharp wrapper to quert=y youTrack.

There is a bug on the bugtracker fro the project:

http://youtrack.codebetter.com/issue/YTSRP-27?projectKey=YTSRP - but it seems this code was rolled back.

After re-enabling the code. I get the following error.

Error converting System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to YouTrackSharp.Issues.IssueStack trace:

```
at JsonFx.Serialization.DataReader`1.ReadSingle(ITextTokenizer`1 tokenizer, IEnumerable`1 tokens, Type targetType)
at JsonFx.Serialization.DataReader`1.Read(String input, Type targetType)
at JsonFx.Serialization.DataReader`1.Read[TResult](String input)
at EasyHttp.Codecs.DefaultDecoder.DecodeToStatic[T](String input, String contentType)
at EasyHttp.Http.HttpResponse.StaticBody[T]()
at YouTrackSharp.Infrastructure.Connection.Get[T](String command)
at YouTrackSharp.Issues.IssueManagement.GetAllIssuesForProject(String projectIdentifier, Int32 max, Int32 start)
at TasksProxy.YouTrackServer.GetProjectIssues(IProxyProject project) in C:\Code\RadicalGeekMVC\TasksProxy\YouTrackServerConnection.cs:line 74
at RadicalGeek.Models.Project.GetTasks() in C:\Code\RadicalGeekMVC\RadicalGeek\Models\Project.cs:line 51
at ASP._Page_Views_Portal_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Code\RadicalGeekMVC\RadicalGeek\Views\Portal\Index.cshtml:line 152
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

this error is thrown on line 103 of the connection class.

var staticBody = httpRequest.Get(_uriConstructor.ConstructBaseUri(command)).StaticBody(); the method looks like this:

```
`        public T Get<T>(string command)
    {
    var httpRequest = CreateHttpRequest();     
    try
    {              
    var staticBody = httpRequest.Get(_uriConstructor.ConstructBaseUri(command)).StaticBody<T>();
    HttpStatusCode = httpRequest.Response.StatusCode;             
    return staticBody;
    }
    catch (HttpException httpException)
    {
    if (httpException.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
    {
    throw new InvalidRequestException(Language.Connection_Get_Insufficient_rights);
    }
    throw;
    }
    }`
```

If anyone can give me any help on this, as I really need to get access to the custom fields for the project.

the code changes I have implimented can be seen as the changes that were rolled back in this changeset:

https://github.com/JetBrains/YouTrackSharp/commit/fc488364b0787deae82d9b0fd3891e21be23bb10

Thank you.

Comment: Since we already followed up in email, let's keep it there. I don't log in to Stackoverflow often (to say at all) so sorry for not noticing this earlier.